# Deleting Root Element and its children based off attribute value XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to delete a student element from the file when selected to be deleted. Problem is, it's only deleting the children and not the parent.

XML file:

```
<StudentRecord>
  <Student StudentNum="S0001">
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Status>Active</Status>
    <Courses>
      <Course Code="TSS8257">
        <Title>Design</Title>
        <Grade>79.00</Grade>
      </Course>
      <Course Code="ART8253">
        <Title>Art</Title>
        <Grade>90.00</Grade>
      </Course>
      <Course Code="CSF8251">
        <Title>Animations</Title>
        <Grade>89.00</Grade>
      </Course>
    </Courses>
  </Student>
<StudentRecord>
```

CS code:

```
   string xmlFilePath = Path.GetFullPath("Data/StudentRecord.xml");

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xmlFilePath);

            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Student");

            XElement root = XElement.Load(xmlFilePath);

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes)
                {
                    if ((attribute.Name == "StudentNum") && (attribute.Value == id))
                    {
                        node.RemoveAll();

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //save xml file.
            doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

The output I receive in the XML file:

```
<Student></Student>
```

The output I want is for everything, including the `<Student></Student>` to be removed.

My past attempt was with linQ, which didn't do anything:

```
    var Student = xdoc.Elements()
        .Descendants("Student")
        .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("StudentNum") == id);

    foreach (var elem in Student)
    {
        elem.Remove();
    }
```

Comment: The XmlDocument isn't picking the changes I suppose? If I were you I'd use XDocument instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `node.RemoveAll();` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do, which is to remove all the node's children and all of its attributes. It does not remove the node. You have to do that from the parent node. Something like this.

```
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```